# Drag and drop issue table to table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a feature that can drag table cell from 1 table to another table cell.

My request is when user drag the cell from `table 1` to `table 2`. The table 1 cell will still have the same texts remaining in the cell. My codes can do that. However, when the user drag cells in table 2. I want the dragged cell text disappear.

For example

```
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td>drag1</td>
        <td>drag2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>drag3</td>
        <td>drag4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

user can drag drag1 from table 1 to table 2 and drag1 still remain in table1

```
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td>drag1</td>
        <td>drag2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>drag3</td>
        <td>drag4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td>drag1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but if user drag cell in table 2, drag1 will disappear and relocate to another cell

```
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td>drag1</td>
        <td>drag2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>drag3</td>
        <td>drag4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>drag1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can't change table classname nor giving a id. so it's a bit tough.

- Table 2 is droppable
- Table 1 is not droppable
- Table 1 source of element dropped to table 2 should stay in table 1 (copy to table 2)
- Table 2 source of element dragged within table 2 to new location should remove source from table 2 and relocate to new position in table 2 at the drop location

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/6/

Comment: Can you clarify, it sounds like you want the text of the cell you are dragging to disappear.  What's the point of making it draggable then?

Comment: Alright you can't give a class or an ID to the table... Can you create two divs with IDs and have each table in a div? We will need something to recognize which table is which... Right now you are running the same code for all the tables on your page.

Comment: Please read my update to clarify if that is correct

Comment: @Seano666 it's just a protection so the user won't have same drag1 texts everywhere in the table 2.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to check if the dragged cell is from table 2 and then clear its content

```
if(target.text().trim() === ""){
    targetText = target.text().trim();
    dragText = drag.text().trim();
    target.html(dragText);
    if(drag.closest('table').is('table:eq(1)'))
        drag.html('&nbsp;');  
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/7/)**

Comment: Seems reasonable to me given the constraints +1